# SSIS project for AdventureWorksDW

Tags: sql-server, ssis, adventureworks

Does anyone know if there is a SSIS sample package that will load the AdventureWorksDW database from the AW OLTP database. I downloaded all the microsoft SSIS samples from codeplex but couldn't find this one.
(The codeplex sample package loads the DB from a bunch of .csv files...)

Thanks in advance...

P.S. Any other SSIS project as reference would be helpfull...

Comment: [SSIS for AdventureWorksDW](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms169917.aspx).  [Great SSIS Tutorial](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/stairway/72494/)

Answer (score 2):

See codeplex for SSIS packages: http://msftisprodsamples.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=SS2008%21AWDataWarehouseRefresh%20Package%20Sample&referringTitle=Home